# Create hexagon with points at top and bottom

Tags: java, awt, polygon

I haven't done any geometry in such a long time that I cannot figure out how to do this.

I created this method:

```
public Polygon getHex(int posX, int posY) {
        Polygon hex = new Polygon();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            hex.addPoint((int) (posX + (50 * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6))),
                    (int) (posY + (50 * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6))));
        }
        return hex;
    }
```

This creates a equilateral Hexagon like this:

```
  _
 / \
 \_/
```

I need a rotated, equilateral hexagon like this:

```
   /\
  |  |
   \/
```

Can anybody help me remember math? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `i * 2` to `(1 + i * 2)`, that will rotate all of your points by pi/6, which should do the trick!